# Regex needed for replacing spaces (%20) with dashes but not the fragments/querystring

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all of the spaces in a url (but not in the querystring or fragment).

regex tried `(\%20)(?=.*\?)`

```
https://www.test.site.nl/some%20subsite/test%20kjahsdhk/?asasdsa%20
https://www.test.site.nl/some%20subsite
https://www.test.site.nl/some%20subsite/#%20?%20
https://www.test.site.nl/some%20subsite/?asdasdasa%20asdkjfhskdjfhsdjk
https://www.test.site.nl/some%20subsite
```

It does match untill the `?` (and not the parts after it).

But unfortunately it doesn't match line 2 and 5 (because they don't have a question mark in it).

Also tried `(?<!\?.*)%20`.

But i got this message/error `lookbehind assertion is not fixed length`

Comment: What is your targeted platform ? Loodahead are fairly new to javascript regexs. A lot of runtimes are still limited to lookbehind assertions only

Answer (score 0):

If your browser supports the newly added LookBehind, you could try this:

```
var url = "https://www.test.site.nl/some%20subsite/?asdasdasa%20asdkjfhskdjfhsdjk";
var result = url.replace(/(%20|\s)+(?<!\?.*)/g, "-");
```

Otherwise, you will need to split the url at the question mark and replace in the first element. After that, recombine the two parts:

```
var url = "https://www.test.site.nl/some%20subsite/?asdasdasa%20asdkjfhskdjfhsdjk".Split("?");
url[0] = url[0].replace(/(%20|\s)+/g, "-");
var result = url.join();
```